# How do I create persistent memory for a java program?

Tags: java, memory, storage

I am a beginner in programming, so I am trying to learn with projects. My newest project is to create an agenda/calendar that is accessible from different computers (like a family calendar) so mom or dad can put up their events and everyone can see everyone's plans.

To a program that can store the instance of a family's agenda so they can go back to it at any time, I assume some sort of database or server to store their information is needed. How could I do this?

I apologize if my question is vague. I am relatively new to programming, but am so eager to keep learning.

Comment: One of the greatest killers of beginning programmers is when they allow their ambition to overcome their ability and become frustrated.Learn the basics first and don't try to build a world-beating program as your first project. The most basic form of persistent storage is a flat file.  Read this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) on input/output. Then ask yourself if you are ready. Walk first, run later.

Answer (score 2):

Memory is [volatile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_memory). For storing data [persistently](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) you need to write it either in [files](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) or in [databases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database).

*Since it is opinion based question, I am putting my opinion.*

- You may begin with learning to read and write to files (text as well as binary).
  While Writing to and reading from files you need to decide in which format you need to store in which format JSON, Yaml, XML or comma-separated or serialize your objects and store them into a file. The choice is yours.

While reading you need to write your own logic to search into them. So while files are a good and easy way to store data, you need to write either your own search mechanism or use document search like Elastic search.

- Another option is to use a database that provides the power of SQL (if using a relational database) to search into your database. In order to use a database, you should learn about databases, reading from and writing to databases, and making a connection to the database in java.

**In my opinion**,

You should begin with the database approach as you can easily query on a date to get all the events present on the given date. Since, you not only want to store the events but you also want to go to a particular date and list out the events planned on that date. So, you need to store your data in such a way in which it is easy to search and read for you.

Also, I advise you to use the Spring framework and Maven which can take care of all the dependency, database connection with minimal configuration. 
You may use [h2 database](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), it is SQLite version and easy to use. Use file-based database, you need not use a server as of now.

**Edit**

Also as suggested by @springe, you can use any ORM like Hibernate to deal with the database which is a secure and recommended way used even in industrial code. Basically it is good practice to use JPA/ Hibernate when performing CRUD operations.

However, since you are new to programming and stuff, get mastery over plain SQL as well as learn good practices like using ORM.

**For references**

You can refer [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/) for references, just google *how to do this and that in java Bealdung* and you will get pretty cool and short guide how to do it.

You will get spring configuration to connect to h2database, maven dependency to for Spring, and database there at Baeldung. Everything is standard and you just need to copy-paste while also learning how things work.

Keep learning, I loved your spirit. :)

Comment: I totally agree with that, but i want to add that i can highly recommend the JPA / Hibernate persistence. Once you know how SQL / Databases work, the JPA Layer saves you a  lot of time and code that has to be written for the basic create,read,update and delete "CRUD" operations. Furthermore it gives you the ability to change the underlying Database without hassle.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Once you use a database with Spring, spring provides you JdbcTemplate and you can then use JPA/ Hibernate along with plain SQL statement. It saves time as well as secure against SQL Injection attacks. It's upto to the programmer whether he is confortable with ORM or old plain SQL style.

Comment: I am using JavaFX for user interface. So I need to store the information that the users put on the calendar, but not the calendar interface itself? In other words, I only store the events the user inputs and when they log back in the program displays those on the calendar? Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

The easiest is Serialization. Serialization takes an object and writes it to a stream using an [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). You can read it back with an ObjectInputStream.

It's trivial because without error checking, it's just a few lines of code.

```
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("calendar.dat");
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(yourCalendar);
  oos.close();
```

Similarly:

```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("calendar.dat");
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  YourCalendar yourCalendar = (YourCalendar)ois.readObject();
  ois.close();
```

Where `yourCalendar` is the master object containing your entire calendar and the appointments, etc.

Since you're not dealing with large amounts of information, it's perfectly adequate.

Now, that said, it's also fraught with danger. The file format is opaque (you can't just open it up in an editor and look at it). It can also be quite brittle. If you change your underlying classes that you're serializing, you may not be able to read a file back in. There's also potential security implications (likely not germane in your case, but they're still there).

Much of those can be mitigated, at the cost of complexity.

Similarly, you can use one of the JSON or XML libraries to serialize your objects out in to one of those text based formats. These are human readable, and can be a bit less sensitive to change than the binary format.

Of course with all of these, they're "all or nothing". In this case, you're writing out the entire object and all of its embedded objects. That means you can can't individually access the data. Nor can you use a 3rd party tool to access the data (like an SQL toolset). But, again, you don't have much data, so having this kind of access is likely not a big deal.

You wouldn't want to use this in a multi-user scenario, as it can not be incrementally updated (again, all or nothing).

But, all that said, for getting up and running, for simple persistence and being cognizant of its limitations, it will do the job for you and let you check this box on your project as you strive to work the other aspects of it. It's easy to enough to start with this and then, later, make a more robust persistence mechanism.